# Этимология слова "наглый"

Tags: этимология

Наглым называют невоспитанного, беспардонного человека, но, тем не менее, в церковнославянских текстах есть понятие "наглая смерть", то есть, внезапная, когда человек умирает без покаяния. Каково же происхождение слова "наглый"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Соврем. слово через др.-рус. **наглъ**, **наглый** восходит к праслав. *naglъ «быстрый, внезапный», которому родственны: др.-инд. anjas, afljasa «прямой», «неожиданный», «быстрый»; гот. anaks «внезапный, быстрый». Это знач. сохраняется в слав. языках. 
Ср. др.-рус.* нагло *«быстро, тотчас»; укр.* наглий *«внезапный, скоропостижный» (смерть), «быстрый»; ст.-сл.* наглъ* «быстрый, скорый» и т. п. У слова **наглый** соврем. знач. собств. рус. фиксируется с XVIII в. Развивалось, вероятно, так: наглый «быстрый, внезапный» > «напористый, требующий быстрого исполнения желаний» > «не считающийся ни с чем» > «бесстыдный», «крайне нахальный».

Answer (score 0):

Действующий наголо, без стеснения. (Моё личное мнение)